# How to ignore class type using Ignore()?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Target Fx: .Net Core 2
CsvHelper: 6.0.0 (latest)

**Person CSV**

```
Name  
Nikhil
```

**Person Class**

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; } // Address has AddLine1, Addline2
}
```

**Person Map**

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person> {
    public PersonMap() {
        AutoMap();
        Map(p => p.Address).Ignore(); // This causes exception
    }
}
```

This is solved by doing:

```
Map(p => p.Address.AddLine1).Ignore();
Map(p => p.Address.AddLine2).Ignore();
```

In reality, the class type I want to ignore has lots of props. So I am curious to know if there's anything CsvHelper already provides to ignore whole type (kind of `Map(p => p.Address).Ignore()`), which I'm not aware of yet.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qKmdip)

Answer (score -1):

I've never used this library before, so take this with a grain of salt:

It appears to be mapping `Address` as a *reference* mapping, rather than a field mapping. It's very likely to be a bug - or at the very least - unexpected behavior in that ignoring a reference mapping actually doesn't do anything. It might be worth reporting this. It should probably recursively ignore all field mappings within it.

That said, there's a workaround: manually remove the reference mapping. You can write an extension:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void RemoveReference<T, TT>(this ClassMap<T> classMap, Expression<Func<T, TT>> expr)
    {
        var memberExpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
        var member = memberExpr.Member;
        var referenceMapsToRemove = classMap.ReferenceMaps.Where(rm => rm.Data.Member == member).ToList();

        foreach (var referenceMapToRemove in referenceMapsToRemove)
        {
            classMap.ReferenceMaps.Remove(referenceMapToRemove);
        }
    }
}
```

And then your code becomes:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        this.RemoveReference(p => p.Address);
    }
}
```

As I noted above, I'm not very familiar with this library. You may have to tweak this to ignore all field mappings within the reference mapping, rather than removing it outright.